# Can I get Skype on my HTC Wildfire in 3?

Tags: skype, htc-wildfire

I recently got HTC Wildfire from 3. On the webpage & in shop they told me that I will be able to do Skype talks. After doing some research I found out that:

1. HTC Wildfire is not officilly supported
2. Some claims that installing the Skype from apk just works

Hence I have following questions:

1. Is it legal to install Skype in such way (according to UK or English law)? On one hand it is advertised feature of phone (or at least it looks like it is) on the other hand Skype is propertary.
2. Which apk files I need?

Comment: Could someone create & add htc-wildfire tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "3"?

Comment: @EricSchaefer: http://www.three.co.uk/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutchison_3G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTC wildfire is supported by 3.  You need to go to favoured on 3 website and choose Skype. Then it begins to download.

Comment: Where's the site link ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't install any random Skype APK that you find on the web as it will charge for calls.  You MUST install the APK from the [Three website](http://www.three.co.uk) to not be charged.

AS an aside, who told you that Three do not support the Wildfire?  They have massive sales of Wildfires on Three and they ARE officially supported by the network.

It is completely legal to install an APK of Skpye from Skpye's website but why would you when the APK that Three provide ensures that your Skype calls on Three are not charged?

Try [this link](http://www.three.co.uk/_popup/Skype) - !!!WARNING, this will only work on UK Three Android handsets!!!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm asking but "Skype calls on Three are not charged" - do you mean that Skype calls does not count into my data limit (I assumed free Skype-to-Skype as marketspeak - i.e. stating that calls from Skype to Skype are free)?

Comment: @Maciej: Skype calls to Skype or any other destination (land-line, mobile) are charged by Skype except on Three Skype-to-Skype calls are free but ONLY with the Three provided Skype client.  They do not count towards your data limit (except in-app presence queries) as the calls themselves are routed through a special number to avoid clogging the 3G network.  This is why you need that particular client and NOT the generic Skype one.

Comment: @Toad: Ok. Sorry for the last clarification - does calls to land-line or mobile from Skype client count towards data limit?

Comment: No calls over Skype cut into your data limit if you have the correct client, whether Skype-to-Skype or Skype-to-landline/mobile.  However, Skype WILL charge you for calls that are Skype-to-landline/mobile (which is charged directly by Skype, not Three)

Answer (score 1):

You need the 3 version of Skype, which surely is supported on the Wildfire version of Android supplied by 3. If you don't use 3's version of Skype you won't get free Skype calls via the 3 mobile network - your calls will subtract from your monthly data allowance.